# Nodejs authorization approaches

Tags: javascript, node.js

Before I have to say that I've found some post related this question but not fully answered.

So I implement a nodejs REST API server, DB with mongoDB, however about authentication i understand the idea, with jwt token it work perfect.

```
/api/login
```

you get response with token. now you can request resource with this token
for example.

```
api/posts/:user_id
```

get all your posts...No problem! query with mongoose findBy.. bla bla!

so for authorization in this case it's easy, check for query param user_id is equal to token (token parse with user_id). boom resources is secure.

but in case that I have some resources they're not reference by user_id, What is best practice to protect this resources?!

**example**

```
api/settings/:settings_id/emails
```

imagine that I know the setting_id of other user, and i authenticated with token. so how server will know this resources is not allowed for me?

Comment: This is usually done using some combination of [HTTP headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication) and/or [cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769011/how-does-cookie-based-authentication-work).

Answer (score 1):

First, you should do more to protect the token in the first place. When you issue a token after a user logs in you should store their token on either web storage like `sessionStrorage` if https is enforced or use an httpOnly cookie (You can add a user-agent/geoip fingerprint in addition to the user_id upon signing this token to add an additional layer of security). Then, when a user makes a request for a protected resource, you can match the fingerprint and user_id you signed the token with to the user they are making the request in behalf of.

You could use something like [passport-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-jwt) as a middleware in express to require authentication on routes. In passport, you define an extractor handler that basically tells it where to look to see if the user has a token and if they do and it validates it adds the `req.user` property that you can use on subsequent requests to determine the user_id of the token bearer. So basically with this approach, you know the user_id on every request which lets you compare that with the user information they are requesting.

```
app.post('/settings/:settings_id/emails', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
    function(req, res) {
        res.send(req.user.id);
    }
);
```