# ASP.NET MVC WebApi 2 Login by token: how to differentiate return codes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, owin

we are facing some problems with the new OWIN auth in web api 2. We are developing mobile apps connecting to API services and we need to differentiate the responses during the login phase. Example: a) Bad Request, b) user not found, c) password incorrect, etc.

Unfortunately, if I intentionally send a wrong password, the /Token endpoint return a "Bad Request" HTTP response, so I can't distinguish between the cases.

Inspecting the web code, I think this is the point (where user is null) where i could decide what kind of response to return back, but how?

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

        var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();


        User user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }

        ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
           OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName, user.ID);
        AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
        context.Validated(ticket);
        context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
    }
```

Thanks in advance for help ;)

Comment: same stuff, i need to check if a user has two step authentication enabled

Answer (score 7):

Returning 400 bad request when the user provides invalid username, or a password, or user is in active is the right way to do it check this [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959947/whats-an-appropriate-http-status-code-to-return-by-a-rest-api-service-for-a-val).

As well my recommendation from security standpoint and once the user try to login to your system, you **should not** return where is the issue coming from, in other words you should return that "Username or password is incorrect". You rarely see systems return what is the incorrect input param when you do login, i.e. "Password is incorrect."

Incase that you have to implement the requirements you asked for, you might build simple POCO class which contains (ErrorCode, ErrorDesc) and return it as JSON object in the response while keeping the http status code 400. And for the client application you will read this JSON object when you receive 400.

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score -3):

It looks like you could do something like

```
context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
return;
```