# API design - Optional body in client request - Status code to return if validation fails

Tags: rest, api-design, http-status-codes, endpoint, status

In our API, one of the endpoint will expect clients to provide body/payload only in certain scenario.

If the API is unable to generate a payload for given request based on the origin of the client then, we want our API to provide response with the right status code to the client, so that they know they have to provide additional information. Once the client fulfills the request with body/payload then the api will process the request as normal.

I just wanted to know is there any standard, predefined status code or procedure to implement this kind of endpoint in API design or do we have to just reject the request with some custom status code and then ask the client to implement a logic based on custom code?.

Thanks,

Vinoth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### HTTP Status codes don't, nor are they intended to, map precisely against every real world error. They represent categories of error.

For example, a 404 means that the resource couldn't be found, but if your path is /customers/11/animals/5 then there are several things which could be wrong with the path. customer 11 may not have an animal 5 for example, or there may be no customer 11. There is no http response for "animal not found". Or your API may not have any calls with that pattern of URL to begin with.

You should return a status code which represents what "category" of error you have (in this case, something was not found), and the response body should contain more specific details about the error. To make things simpler, I find it helpful if the data structure is the same for a success and error (it makes parsing much easier) with a "data" field which varies per response.

Here is one example:

```
status code: 404 not found
body: { 
    "messageDetailCode" :"CustomerNotFound", 
    "messageDetail" : "Customer not found", 
    "data" : null 
}
```

Further reading:

[What's an appropriate HTTP status code to return by a REST API service for a validation failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959947/whats-an-appropriate-http-status-code-to-return-by-a-rest-api-service-for-a-val?rq=1)