# What is the best HTTP status code error for failed password update?

Tags: rest, api, http-status-codes

I'm building some REST API to be used in a native iOS/Android app.
One of the endpoints allows the user to update his password by providing 2 fields: `old_password` and `password`.

Which HTTP status code should I in the situation where the `old_password` is incorrect?

My first thought was a `401` error but I already use it when the authentication token is invalid and it automatically triggers a logout in the app.

`400` doesn't seem to fit because the request is actually semantically correct, it is a specific authentication error. Maybe `422`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One thing to keep in mind is that status codes, like response headers, are *metadata*; they are there so that generic components that know nothing about the details of your API can participate intelligently -- for example, by invalidating caches, or throwing up dialogs to collect authentication credentials.

> 400 doesn't seem to fit because the request is actually semantically correct

In practice, `400` is usually fine; clients are supposed to treat an [unrecognized](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6) 4xx class status code as they would treat 400.  Put another way, you can use 400 unless you specifically want to induce a different behavior by the generic components.

For your specific case, [409 Conflict](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8) is probably the closest match

> The 409 (Conflict) status code indicates that the request could not be completed due to a conflict with *the current state of the target resource*.  This code is used in situations where the user might be able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request.  The server SHOULD generate a payload that includes enough information for a user to recognize the source of the conflict.

[RFC 5789 suggests](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789#section-2.2) a distinction between `409` and `422` that may be interesting.  Paraphrasing this distinction

> 422: This might include attempts to modify a resource in a way that would cause the resource to become invalid
> 409: the request cannot be applied given the state of the resource.

You can also make [a reasonable argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11982856/54734) that the entire 4xx class of response codes is inappropriate.  For example, if the request method is [POST](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3), then the server is expected to

> process the representation enclosed in the request according to the resource's own specific semantics

Which it did; successfully, even.  It just didn't produce the most commonly expected successful result.

On the other hand, the JSON Patch would argue the other direction; your attempt to change the password would probably look something like

```
[
    { "op": "test", "path": "/password", "value": "old_password" },
    { "op": "replace", "path": "/password", "value": "new_password" }
]
```

If you provided the wrong password in the `test`, then that operation would be considered *unsuccessful*, which would in turn mean that the PATCH is unsuccessful.  That in turn would invoke the arguments for error handling as described in [HTTP Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789#section-2.2).